# Calling a GoogleSheet Range through a variable

Tags: python, pandas, wxpython, google-sheets-api

I am trying to make a range call through a variable that will be written by the user, but I always get the cannot parse error but I know it's a real tab

```
def on_commencer(self,event):
Range = ('RANGE_'+self.NumSerie.GetValue())
data = pull_sheet_data(SCOPES,RECETTES_SHEET_ID,Range)#RANGE_REC100
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
print(df)
```

which goes with my other part

```
def pull_sheet_data(SCOPES,SPREADSHEET_ID,DATA_TO_PULL):
#creds = gsheet_api_check(SCOPES)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=DATA_TO_PULL).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])

if not values:
    print('No data found.')
else:
    rows = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=DATA_TO_PULL).execute()           
    data = rows.get('values')
    print("COMPLETE: Data copied")
    return data
```

if instead of Range I write RANGE_REC100 it works, but not if in my app I write REC100 which give me the full name RANGE_REC100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it i was trying to call a constant through a string but what i was needing was to build a dictionary for those stumbling on a similar problem my new code is

```
def on_commencer(self,event):
    Range = ('RANGE_'+self.NumSerie.GetValue())
    Tankask = TankRange[Range]
    data = pull_sheet_data(SCOPES,RECETTES_SHEET_ID,Tankask)#RANGE_REC100
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
    print(df)
```

My constant were list like that

```
RANGE_REC100P = 'REC100'
RANGE_CB100 = 'REC100!A2:C4'
RANGE_REC100_DW = 'REC100!A10:C30'
```

and now it look like this

```
TankRange = {
'RANGE_REC100P'               : ('REC100'),
'RANGE_CB100'                 : ('REC100!A2:C4'),
'RANGE_REC100_DW'             : ('REC100!A10:C30')}
```